# How to achieve drill down and drill up functionality in Power BI table visual?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I'm trying to implement drill down and drill up functionality within a table visual in Power BI, but I'm having trouble finding a straightforward way to do it. From my understanding, the table visual doesn't have built-in support for drill down and drill up like other visuals such as the matrix.

Is there a way to achieve similar functionality within the table visual? I want users to be able to navigate through different levels of data granularity, such as from year to quarter to month, directly within the table.

I've tried exploring options like creating hierarchies in the data model and using calculated columns, but I haven't been able to achieve the desired result. Can someone provide guidance on how to implement drill down and drill up functionality in a Power BI table visual, or suggest alternative approaches to accomplish this?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Update your question with an example of the Table visual so we can see what kids or fields it has.

Comment: You Will be able to Achieve Drilling Operations only if the data has granuality and hierarchy in the Data Model.